# Symmetric group isomorphic to semidirect product of Alternating group and Z/2Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

[image]

I'm having a hard time understanding why $A_n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong S_n$.

I understand that $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$. But that's about it. What would the $\alpha$: $\mathbb{Z}$$_2$$\longrightarrow$Aut($A_n$) be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick an odd element of $ S_n $ of order two; for example, a transposition. Then conjugation by that element is an order two automorphism of $ A_n $.

Comment: Could I just choose $S_2$ then or no?

Comment: That question does not make sense! You have to pick an element of $S_n$ of order $2$, for example $(1,2)$. Then the subgroup ${\mathbb Z}_2$ in the semidirect product is the subgroup consiting of that element together with the identity.